# convert decimal to significant digits

Tags: python

Is there a function in python that could convert decimal to 3-4 significant digits, 
eg:

```
55820.02932238298323 to 5.58e4
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "convert to" you mean that you want a string formatted like that, you can use the `%e` format option:

```
>>> '%.2e' % 55820.02932238298323
'5.58e+04'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [50]: "{0:.2e}".format(55820.02932238298323)
Out[50]: '5.58e+04'
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is for output purposes you can just [use string formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax):

```
>>> "%.2e" % 55820.02932238298323
'5.58e+04'
>>> "{:.2e}".format(55820.02932238298323)
'5.58e+04'
```

If you want the rounded value to be a `float` [take a look at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python).