# Rounding to significant figures in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I've tried searching this and can't find a satisfactory answer.

I want to take a list/array of numbers and round them all to n significant figures. I have written a function to do this, but I was wondering if there is a standard method for this? I've searched but can't find it. Example:

```
In:  [  0.0, -1.2366e22, 1.2544444e-15, 0.001222 ], n=2
Out: [ 0.00, -1.24e22,        1.25e-15,  1.22e-3 ]
```

Thanks

Comment: The basic question is what do you want it for. Why do you want to limit the precision in intermediate calculations, instead of doing them in full precision and just round/print rounded in the very end?

Comment: If it helps I need to return high precision values from a function calculated at convenient input values. Input values may cover a number of orders of magnitude and must allow for 0 values, -/+ve values and -/+ve exponents, as above. In this case, by "convenient" I mean values rounded to n significant figures. Thus I need these rounded values pre-calculation. My application aside, rounding to significant figures is a fundamental task, your comment would suggest we have no use for functions like around(x,n), round(x,n) ... etc.

Comment: Answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python, but with base python.

Answer (score 24):

Testing all of the already proposed solutions, I find they either

1. convert to and from strings, which is inefficient
2. can't handle negative numbers
3. can't handle arrays
4. have some numerical errors.

Here's my attempt at a solution which should handle all of these things. (Edit 2020-03-18: added `np.asarray` as suggested by A. West.)

```
def signif(x, p):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    x_positive = np.where(np.isfinite(x) & (x != 0), np.abs(x), 10**(p-1))
    mags = 10 ** (p - 1 - np.floor(np.log10(x_positive)))
    return np.round(x * mags) / mags
```

Testing:

```
def scottgigante(x, p):
    x_positive = np.where(np.isfinite(x) & (x != 0), np.abs(x), 10**(p-1))
    mags = 10 ** (p - 1 - np.floor(np.log10(x_positive)))
    return np.round(x * mags) / mags

def awest(x,p):
    return float(f'%.{p-1}e'%x)

def denizb(x,p):
    return float(('%.' + str(p-1) + 'e') % x)

def autumn(x, p):
    return np.format_float_positional(x, precision=p, unique=False, fractional=False, trim='k')

def greg(x, p):
    return round(x, -int(np.floor(np.sign(x) * np.log10(abs(x)))) + p-1)

def user11336338(x, p):         
    xr = (np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x)))).astype(int)
    xr=10.**xr*np.around(x/10.**xr,p-1)   
    return xr

def dmon(x, p):
    if np.all(np.isfinite(x)):
        eset = np.seterr(all='ignore')
        mags = 10.0**np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x)))  # omag's
        x = np.around(x/mags,p-1)*mags             # round(val/omag)*omag
        np.seterr(**eset)
        x = np.where(np.isnan(x), 0.0, x)           # 0.0 -> nan -> 0.0
    return x

def seanlake(x, p):
    __logBase10of2 = 3.010299956639811952137388947244930267681898814621085413104274611e-1
    xsgn = np.sign(x)
    absx = xsgn * x
    mantissa, binaryExponent = np.frexp( absx )

    decimalExponent = __logBase10of2 * binaryExponent
    omag = np.floor(decimalExponent)

    mantissa *= 10.0**(decimalExponent - omag)

    if mantissa < 1.0:
        mantissa *= 10.0
        omag -= 1.0

    return xsgn * np.around( mantissa, decimals=p - 1 ) * 10.0**omag

solns = [scottgigante, awest, denizb, autumn, greg, user11336338, dmon, seanlake]

xs = [
    1.114, # positive, round down
    1.115, # positive, round up
    -1.114, # negative
    1.114e-30, # extremely small
    1.114e30, # extremely large
    0, # zero
    float('inf'), # infinite
    [1.114, 1.115e-30], # array input
]
p = 3

print('input:', xs)
for soln in solns:
    print(f'{soln.__name__}', end=': ')
    for x in xs:
        try:
            print(soln(x, p), end=', ')
        except Exception as e:
            print(type(e).__name__, end=', ')
    print()
```

Results:

```
input: [1.114, 1.115, -1.114, 1.114e-30, 1.114e+30, 0, inf, [1.114, 1.115e-30]]
scottgigante: 1.11, 1.12, -1.11, 1.11e-30, 1.11e+30, 0.0, inf, [1.11e+00 1.12e-30], 
awest: 1.11, 1.11, -1.11, 1.11e-30, 1.11e+30, 0.0, inf, TypeError, 
denizb: 1.11, 1.11, -1.11, 1.11e-30, 1.11e+30, 0.0, inf, TypeError, 
autumn: 1.11, 1.11, -1.11, 0.00000000000000000000000000000111, 1110000000000000000000000000000., 0.00, inf, TypeError, 
greg: 1.11, 1.11, -1.114, 1.11e-30, 1.11e+30, ValueError, OverflowError, TypeError, 
user11336338: 1.11, 1.12, -1.11, 1.1100000000000002e-30, 1.1100000000000001e+30, nan, nan, [1.11e+00 1.12e-30], 
dmon: 1.11, 1.12, -1.11, 1.1100000000000002e-30, 1.1100000000000001e+30, 0.0, inf, [1.11e+00 1.12e-30], 
seanlake: 1.11, 1.12, -1.11, 1.1100000000000002e-30, 1.1100000000000001e+30, 0.0, inf, ValueError,
```

Timing:

```
def test_soln(soln):
    try:
        soln(np.linspace(1, 100, 1000), 3)
    except Exception:
        [soln(x, 3) for x in np.linspace(1, 100, 1000)]

for soln in solns:
    print(soln.__name__)
    %timeit test_soln(soln)
```

Results:

```
scottgigante
135 µs ± 15.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
awest
2.23 ms ± 430 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
denizb
2.18 ms ± 352 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
autumn
2.92 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
greg
14.1 ms ± 1.21 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
user11336338
157 µs ± 50.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
dmon
142 µs ± 8.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
seanlake
20.7 ms ± 994 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Comment: Love this!
However your method only works for numpy arrays at the query: `x!=0`.  Maybe add
`if not isinstance(x, np.ndarray):
 x = np.array(x)`

Comment: you are a hero!

Comment: This is a GREAT answer!

Comment: I feel this merits a pull request to numpy.

Answer (score 14):

Most of the solutions given here either (a) don't give correct significant figures, or (b) are unnecessarily complex.

If your goal is *display* formatting, then [numpy.format_float_positional](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_positional.html) supports the desired behaviour directly.  The following fragment returns the float `x` formatted to 4 significant figures, with scientific notation suppressed.

```
import numpy as np
x=12345.6
np.format_float_positional(x, precision=4, unique=False, fractional=False, trim='k')
> 12340.
```

Comment: The perfect answer :)

Comment: Here's a snippet to vectorize it

https://gist.github.com/jpcbertoldo/92370a121ac4f77775fb9c9362ea173e

Comment: When I run the code example in Numpy 1.25.2 I get a result that is different in two ways. I get `'12350.'`, which is a string, and not the float `12340.`.

Answer (score 13):

First a criticism: you're counting the number of significant figures wrong. In your example you want n=3, not 2.

It is possible to get around most of the edge cases by letting numpy library functions handle them if you use the function that makes the binary version of this algorithm simple: frexp. As a bonus, this algorithm will also run much faster because it never calls the log function.

```
#The following constant was computed in maxima 5.35.1 using 64 bigfloat digits of precision
__logBase10of2 = 3.010299956639811952137388947244930267681898814621085413104274611e-1

import numpy as np

def RoundToSigFigs_fp( x, sigfigs ):
"""
Rounds the value(s) in x to the number of significant figures in sigfigs.
Return value has the same type as x.

Restrictions:
sigfigs must be an integer type and store a positive value.
x must be a real value or an array like object containing only real values.
"""
if not ( type(sigfigs) is int or type(sigfigs) is long or
         isinstance(sigfigs, np.integer) ):
    raise TypeError( "RoundToSigFigs_fp: sigfigs must be an integer." )

if sigfigs <= 0:
    raise ValueError( "RoundToSigFigs_fp: sigfigs must be positive." )

if not np.all(np.isreal( x )):
    raise TypeError( "RoundToSigFigs_fp: all x must be real." )

#temporarily suppres floating point errors
errhanddict = np.geterr()
np.seterr(all="ignore")

matrixflag = False
if isinstance(x, np.matrix): #Convert matrices to arrays
    matrixflag = True
    x = np.asarray(x)

xsgn = np.sign(x)
absx = xsgn * x
mantissas, binaryExponents = np.frexp( absx )

decimalExponents = __logBase10of2 * binaryExponents
omags = np.floor(decimalExponents)

mantissas *= 10.0**(decimalExponents - omags)

if type(mantissas) is float or isinstance(mantissas, np.floating):
    if mantissas < 1.0:
        mantissas *= 10.0
        omags -= 1.0
        
else: #elif np.all(np.isreal( mantissas )):
    fixmsk = mantissas < 1.0, 
    mantissas[fixmsk] *= 10.0
    omags[fixmsk] -= 1.0

result = xsgn * np.around( mantissas, decimals=sigfigs - 1 ) * 10.0**omags
if matrixflag:
    result = np.matrix(result, copy=False)

np.seterr(**errhanddict)
return result
```

And it handles all of your cases correctly, including infinite, nan, 0.0, and a subnormal number:

```
>>> eglist = [  0.0, -1.2366e22, 1.2544444e-15, 0.001222, 0.0, 
...        float("nan"), float("inf"), float.fromhex("0x4.23p-1028"), 
...        0.5555, 1.5444, 1.72340, 1.256e-15, 10.555555  ]
>>> eglist
[0.0, -1.2366e+22, 1.2544444e-15, 0.001222, 0.0, 
nan, inf, 1.438203867284623e-309, 
0.5555, 1.5444, 1.7234, 1.256e-15, 10.555555]
>>> RoundToSigFigs(eglist, 3)
array([  0.00000000e+000,  -1.24000000e+022,   1.25000000e-015,
         1.22000000e-003,   0.00000000e+000,               nan,
                     inf,   1.44000000e-309,   5.56000000e-001,
         1.54000000e+000,   1.72000000e+000,   1.26000000e-015,
         1.06000000e+001])
>>> RoundToSigFigs(eglist, 1)
array([  0.00000000e+000,  -1.00000000e+022,   1.00000000e-015,
         1.00000000e-003,   0.00000000e+000,               nan,
                     inf,   1.00000000e-309,   6.00000000e-001,
         2.00000000e+000,   2.00000000e+000,   1.00000000e-015,
         1.00000000e+001])
```

Edit: 2016/10/12 I found an edge case that the original code handled wrong. I have placed a [fuller version of the code](https://github.com/odysseus9672/SELPythonLibs/blob/master/SigFigRounding.py) in a GitHub repository.

Edit: 2019/03/01 Replace with recoded version.

Edit: 2020/11/19 Replace with vectorized version from Github that handles arrays. Note that preserving input data types, where possible, was also a goal of this code.

Comment: The constant `__logBase10of2` has far more precision than a float, and the python interpreter will truncate most of that.

Comment: Indeed, that is so. The thing is that the float precision can change at some point, and this provides a small amount of future proofing. Even better would be to use Python's decimal package, with its tunable precision, to calculate it before converting to floating point.

Comment: `omags` is not defined in the inline example. The longer example you linked to doesn't run in python 3.

Comment: @rob I just submitted a major reworking of the linked code. In all of my tests with Python 3.6 none of them failed, even before I reworked the code.

Answer (score 10):

Is [numpy.set_printoptions](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) what you're looking for?

```
import numpy as np
np.set_printoptions(precision=2)
print np.array([  0.0, -1.2366e22, 1.2544444e-15, 0.001222 ])
```

Gives:

```
[  0.00e+00  -1.24e+22   1.25e-15   1.22e-03]
```

**Edit:**

[numpy.around](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.around.html#numpy.around) appears to solve aspects of this problem if you're trying to transform the data. However, it doesn't do what you want in cases where the exponent is negative.

Comment: Not really. I looked at this, but I actually want the results for manipulation. I was thinking I could convert to string, using something like this and convert back, but this seems messy and likely extremely slow when applied to large arrays.

Comment: @dmon why are you talking about this kind or awkward solution if you already have one?

Comment: @Simon. Its a short simple question. "Is there a STANDARD WAY way of rounding m numbers to n significant figures?" A perfectly fine answer is "no there is not"!! I don't really know what point you're trying to make

Comment: @dmon Your question is clear enough. But the print/read method is not likely to bring you the standard method you are looking for. I haven't found any either, for that matter. Only a mail mentioning a [proposal](http://mail.scipy.org/pipermail/numpy-discussion/2001-September/013232.html).

Answer (score 3):

From the example numbers you have I think you mean significant figures rather than decimal places  (`-1.2366e22` to 0 decimal places is still `-1.2366e22`).

This piece of code works for me, I've always thought there should be an inbuilt function though:

```
def Round_To_n(x, n):
    return round(x, -int(np.floor(np.sign(x) * np.log10(abs(x)))) + n)

>>> Round_To_n(1.2544444e-15,2)
1.25e-15

>>> Round_To_n(2.128282321e3, 6)
2130.0
```

Comment: Hi Greg. Yes typo in my question sorry, will fix. My title clearly states significant figures though. Also, as stated, I have written a function to do this, what I'm asking is if there is a built in function, or a standard method to round to significant figures? It's starting to appear as thought there is not, which is a perfectly good answer. Finally your function fails for my first two test cases! Cheers for trying dude!

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so reasonably safe to say this is not allowed for in standard functionality. To close this off then, this is my attempt at a robust solution. It's rather ugly/non-pythonic and prob illustrates better then anything why I asked this question, so please feel free to correct or beat :)

```
import numpy as np

def round2SignifFigs(vals,n):
    """
    (list, int) -> numpy array
    (numpy array, int) -> numpy array

    In: a list/array of values
    Out: array of values rounded to n significant figures

    Does not accept: inf, nan, complex

    >>> m = [0.0, -1.2366e22, 1.2544444e-15, 0.001222]
    >>> round2SignifFigs(m,2)
    array([  0.00e+00,  -1.24e+22,   1.25e-15,   1.22e-03])
    """

    if np.all(np.isfinite(vals)) and np.all(np.isreal((vals))):
        eset = np.seterr(all='ignore')
        mags = 10.0**np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(vals)))  # omag's
        vals = np.around(vals/mags,n)*mags             # round(val/omag)*omag
        np.seterr(**eset)
        vals[np.where(np.isnan(vals))] = 0.0           # 0.0 -> nan -> 0.0
    else:
        raise IOError('Input must be real and finite')
    return vals
```

Nearest I get to neat does not account for 0.0, nan, inf or complex:

```
>>> omag      = lambda x: 10**np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x)))
>>> signifFig = lambda x, n: (np.around(x/omag(x),n)*omag(x))
```

giving:

```
>>> m = [0.0, -1.2366e22, 1.2544444e-15, 0.001222]
>>> signifFig(m,2)
array([ nan, -1.24e+22,   1.25e-15,   1.22e-03])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a version of **Autumns** answer which is vectorized so it can be applied to an **array of floats** not just a single **float**.

```
x = np.array([12345.6, 12.5673])
def sf4(x):
    x = float(np.format_float_positional(x, precision=4, unique=False, fractional=False,trim='k'))
    return x
vec_sf4 = np.vectorize(sf4)

vec_sf4(x)

>>>np.array([12350., 12.57])
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution that uses the logic built into pythons string formatting system:

```
def round_sig(f, p):
    return float(('%.' + str(p) + 'e') % f)
```

Test with the following example:

```
for f in [0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 1000]:
    f *= 1.23456789
    print('%e --> %f' % (f, round_sig(f,3)))
```

which yields:

```
1.234568e-02 --> 0.012350
1.234568e-01 --> 0.123500
1.234568e+00 --> 1.235000
1.234568e+01 --> 12.350000
1.234568e+02 --> 123.500000
1.234568e+03 --> 1235.000000
1.234568e+03 --> 1235.000000
```

Best of luck!

(If you like lambdas use:

```
round_sig = lambda f,p: float(('%.' + str(p) + 'e') % f)
```

)

Answer (score 0):

I like Greg's very short effective routine above.  However, it suffers from two drawbacks.  One is that it doesn't work for `x<0`, not for me anyway.   (That `np.sign(x)` should be removed.)   Another is that it does not work if `x` is an array. I've fixed both of those problems with the routine below. Notice that I've changed the definition of `n`.

```
import numpy as np

def Round_n_sig_dig(x, n):

    xr = (np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x)))).astype(int)
    xr=10.**xr*np.around(x/10.**xr,n-1)   
    return xr
```

Answer (score 0):

## For Scalars

```
sround = lambda x,p: float(f'%.{p-1}e'%x)
```

#### Example

```
>>> print( sround(123.45, 2) )
120.0
```

## For Arrays

Use [Scott Gigante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888924/10450752)'s `signif(x, p)`
[fig1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xr9i5.png)
[fig2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rvv7x.png)

Answer (score 0):

I got quite frustrated after scouring the internet and not finding an answer for this, so I wrote my own piece of code. Hope this is what you're looking for

```
import numpy as np
from numpy import ma

exp = np.floor(ma.log10(abs(X)).filled(0))
ans = np.round(X*10**-exp, sigfigs-1) * 10**exp
```

Just plug in your np array X and the required number of significant figures. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

For (display-) formatting in exponential notation, `numpy.format_float_scientific(x, precision = n)` (where *x* is the number to be formatted) seems to work well. The method  returns a `string`. (This is similar to @Autumn's answer)

Here is an example:

```
>>> x = 7.92398e+05
>>> print(numpy.format_float_scientific(x, precision = 3))
7.924e+05
```

Here, the argument *precision = n* fixes the number of decimals in the mantissa (by rounding off). It is possible to re-convert back this to `float` type...and that would obviously keep only the digits present in the string. It would be converted to a positional float format though... more work would be required - so I guess the re-conversion is probably quite a bad idea for large set of numbers.

Also, this doesn't work with iterables...look the [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.format_float_scientific.html) up for more info.

Comment: @MarkParris I seem to have mentioned that.

Answer (score 0):

One more solution which works well. Doing the test from @ScottGigante, it would be second best with a timing of 1.75ms.

```
import math

def sig_dig(x, n_sig_dig = 5):
  num_of_digits = len(str(x).replace(".", ""))
  if n_sig_dig >= num_of_digits:
      return x
  n = math.floor(math.log10(abs(x)) + 1 - n_sig_dig)
  result = round(x * 10**(-n)) * 10**n
  return result
```

And if it should be applied also to list/arrays you can vectorize it as

```
sig_dig_vec = np.vectorize(sig_dig)
```

Credit: answer inspired by [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60876419/12454103)