# changing float to string

Tags: python-3.x, floating-point, fwrite

I used `float` to read a number in a text file. for example : `number=float(25.0000)` ,then I tried to write this number in another file, so I used `str` format. But what I saw in my text file was like `25.0` .I like to know what should I do to have exactly the number that I had before.(`25.0000`)
I also like to know if even I don't know how many decimal the number has it is possible or not?

```
with open(file , 'w') as f:
    num =float(25.0000)
    f.write(str(num))
```

Comment: You do have the same number, what you do not have is the same string representation of that number.  Suggest: https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your desired result with:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    num = float(25.0000)
    f.write('%.4f' % num))
```

([DOCS](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html))

Comment: That is a problem without an easy answer. One possible answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23749691/7311767 If you read the number out of a file, you can check then.  You can also work with fixed point numbers.  Or maybe study the sceince a bit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures

Answer (score 2):

Use the `format()` function:

```
with open(file, 'w') as f:
    num = float(25.0000)
    f.write(str(format(num, '.4f')))
```

Answer (score 2):

This will work..

```
num=float(25.0000)
f=open('a.txt','w')
f.write("%0.4f"%num)
```

Here, % is the text formatting operator and 0.5 is replaced by the general syntax `<fieldWidth>.<precission>` and f stands for float data type.