# Logarithmic slider with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I just implemented a slider in my plot which works great. (I used this example: http://matplotlib.org/examples/widgets/slider_demo.html) Now my question is if it is possible to make the slider logarithmic. My values range between 0 and 1 and I want to make changes from 0.01 to 0.02 and so on but also from 0.01 to 0.5. That is why I think a logarithmic scale would be nice. Also if this isn't doable with a slider do you then have other ideas how to implement this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply `np.log()` the value of the slider. However then the label next to it would be incorrect. You need to manually set the text of `valtext` of the slider to the log-value:

```
def update(val):
    amp = np.log(slider.val)
    slider.valtext.set_text(amp)
```

Comment: This worked and I used it in my answer below, but it doesn't update the value until a change is made to the slider.  So at the beginning it shows the untransformed slider value.  Is there a way to call this function at initialization?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been few years but I think it still is useful.
The previous answer is simple and straightforward but can be a problem with the inital values not correctly displayed for example.
You can directly create a log slider by creating a new class inheriting from the matplotlib slider and edit the function that set the value like so :

```
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider


class Sliderlog(Slider):

"""Logarithmic slider.

    Takes in every method and function of the matplotlib's slider.

    Set slider to *val* visually so the slider still is lineat but display 10**val next to the slider.

    Return 10**val to the update function (func)"""

    def set_val(self, val):

        xy = self.poly.xy
        if self.orientation == 'vertical':
            xy[1] = 0, val
            xy[2] = 1, val
        else:
            xy[2] = val, 1
            xy[3] = val, 0
        self.poly.xy = xy
        self.valtext.set_text(self.valfmt % 10**val)   # Modified to display 10**val instead of val
        if self.drawon:
            self.ax.figure.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.val = val
        if not self.eventson:
            return
        for cid, func in self.observers.items():
                func(10**val)
```

You use it the same way you use the slider but instead of call :

```
    Slider(ax, label, valmin, valmax, valinit=0.5, valfmt='%1.2f', closedmin=True, closedmax=True, slidermin=None, slidermax=None, dragging=True, valstep=None, orientation='horizontal')
```

Just call :

```
    Sliderlog(ax, label, valmin, valmax, valinit=0.5, valfmt='%1.2f', closedmin=True, closedmax=True, slidermin=None, slidermax=None, dragging=True, valstep=None, orientation='horizontal',
```

Be careful, if you want to have 10^3 as initial value you have to pass in valinit=3 not 10**3. Same for valmax and valmin. You can use log10(desired_value) if you can not easily type it.

Comment: I like the idea, but in the end this didn't quite work out for me. Empty `valfmt` is not handled and `observers` is deprecated in version 3.4. So this will not age well I think. But perhaps it could be improved.

Answer (score 1):

Building on the answer by @NilsWerner, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71186246/1609514), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915378/rounding-to-significant-figures-in-numpy), here is a log slider for the case where you want to only allow a discrete set of values shown as tick labels. I find this is useful in the case of a log slider.

The values are pre-specified.  In this example, my variable is named 'R'.

```
R_value = 0.5

ax_R = plt.axes([0.25, 0.15, 0.65, 0.03])
R_values = [0.01, 0.02, 0.05, 0.1, 0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0, 5.0, 10.0]
R_values = np.array(sorted(set(R_values))
slider_values = np.log10(R_values)
valinit = slider_values[(np.abs(R_values - R_value)).argmin()]  # snap to nearest
slider_R_log = Slider(
    ax_R, 'R',
    slider_values[0], slider_values[-1], 
    valinit=valinit,
    valstep=slider_values
)
value_formatter = lambda x: np.format_float_positional(
    x, precision=1, unique=False, 
    fractional=False, trim='k'
)
ax_R.add_artist(ax_R.xaxis)
ax_R.set_xticks(slider_values)
ax_R.set_xticklabels([value_formatter(x) for x in R_values])

def update(val):
    R_value = 10 ** val
    val_str = value_formatter(R_value)
    slider_R_log.valtext.set_text(val_str)

slider_R_log.on_changed(update)
```

It looks like this:
[image: Screenshot of a horizontal slider with tick labels]

I can't believe this is so difficult...