# Logarithmic slider in Altair

Tags: python, altair

Altair offers sliders with evenly spaced values. However, is it also possible to have arbitrary values the slider maps to? I'm especially interested in a logarithmic slider with values such as 1, 10, 100 (i.e. 1 on the left end, 10 in the middle, 100 on the right end of the slider).

An example of what I'm looking for can be found in [this JavaScript-related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/846249/7411135) (which has a nice live demo).

This seems to be [possible with matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39960977/7411135). (UPDATE: This is actually not a good example. Please only have a look at the JavaScript example.)
Is it also possible with Altair?

Answer (score 1):

Depending what exactly you want to do with the slider, you could use calculate transforms to calculate the exponent of the slider value. For example:

```
import altair as alt

slider = alt.binding_range(min=0, max=10, step=1, name='log(C)')
sel = alt.selection_single(name="sel", fields=['logC'],
                           bind=slider, init={'logC': 0})

alt.Chart(
    alt.sequence(0, 100, 1, 'x')
).transform_calculate(
    y=alt.datum.x ** 2 / alt.expr.exp(sel.logC)
).mark_line().encode(
    x='x:Q',
    y=alt.Y('y:Q', title='x^2/C'),
).add_selection(
    sel
)
```

[image]

You can try it interactively [here](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4KABGBEAmCGAutIC4zEgZwKYEcCuWAdgMZYpqaIBO85ADADRQbwD2ADuQIx2PPxZOqLk0iwM5SAA9IAX1kNwUALawqAa0kAbAJaEyiiJCLFW0PQHNyoCEZmp0AMx1Yt0STNHwAnuzKpIfFhCeB1EUIA3MgUlI29rSGdXdwD4r19-KCCQsIQdKMgvMK1M6QA9ACYAegBhOSUYo2wS4lDWQmtY5ldO21tIHz9JDEsSwq6jJLcJVABtSC1WCzqAXUM+qAAjPRS0Cf69djxaAKpgiwN9o2U9enWNlVh7MB57jcpBbje+yEJYZVKiwsAAoagBKSD7RrvPRhBJAuqoOiyLooiDQgZnQgYRysKjKcizdDEWBaYh4LQIUrA9isADuwLg8DwygAdFIGBUwWAqmAsFJ2MDmqyEWCIaJxJJ4rI1kpIKZCM4rA5IBEXHSEgrQoQ8Kw8BgAOo6aDwAAW5AALLxRFq9Lr9QAJLA6Cymk5gADMvHkIFkQA).

Comment: Thanks for your effort, Jake! Your support is amazing! :)
Now I realize that the matplotlib example was actually bad, I'm really sorry. (It was late at night here in Europe ^^)
I will leave the question open for now. Maybe there is a chance to display C directly in the slider (as in the JavaScript example I linked in the question) instead of log(C).
But definitely +1 :)