# Round a series to N number of significant figures

Tags: python, pandas, math, rounding

I have a dataframe of floats and I need make a function that will take a column and round all the values to N number of significant figures

So the column might look something like:

```
123.949
23.87 
1.9865
0.0129500
```

and if I wanted to round to 3 significant figures I would pass the column and 3 to the function to get this

```
124.0
23.9
1.99
0.013
```

How can I do this efficiently without looping through the column?

I have an equation that will calculate the significant figures for a number

```
round(x, N-int(floor(log10(abs(x))))
```

but it doesn't work on a series or dataframe

Comment: use the pandas series round method, see: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.round.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use, `pandas.Series.apply` which implements a function element wise across an axis (column or row):

```
df.col.apply(lambda x: round(x, N - int(floor(log10(abs(x))))))
```

Note that you can't really use `pandas.DataFrame.apply` here since the round function should be element wise, not on the entire axis.

The difference would be that your function input is `float` instead of getting an `array`.

Another option would be `applymap` which implements a function element-wise on the entire `pandas.DataFrame`.

```
df.applymap(lambda x: round(x, N - int(floor(log10(abs(x))))))
```

Comment: @jezrael Not sure if that what you were going at, but feel free to append any further explanation needed in the comments.

Comment: no, I we dont understand each other. I think code only answers are bad :) plus1

Answer (score 3):

Here is another take at applying your custom function over the series in a dataframe. However, the in-built round() seems to round fractional parts down when the last digit is 5, so in your example you'd actually get 0.0129 instead of 0.013. I tried to remedy this. Also added the ability to set the number of significant figures as an argument to get the rounder you want to apply.

```
import pandas as pd
from math import floor, log10

df = pd.DataFrame({'floats':[123.949, 23.87, 1.9865, 0.0129500]})

def smarter_round(sig):
    def rounder(x):
        offset = sig - floor(log10(abs(x)))
        initial_result = round(x, offset)
        if str(initial_result)[-1] == '5' and initial_result == x:
            return round(x, offset - 2)
        else:
            return round(x, offset - 1)
    return rounder

print(df['floats'].apply(smarter_round(3)))

Out:
    0    124.000
    1     23.900
    2      1.990
    3      0.013
    Name: floats, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 2):

With large dataframes, .apply can be slow.  The best solution I have seen came from [Scott Gigante](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59888924/12720351) addressing the same question directly for numpy.

Here is a lightly modified version of his answer simply adding some pandas wrapping.  The solution is fast and robust.

```
from typing import Union
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def significant_digits(df: Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series], 
                       significance: int, 
                       inplace: bool = False
                       ) -> Union[pd.DataFrame, pd.Series, None]:
    
    # Create a positive data vector with a place holder for NaN / inf data
    data = df.values
    data_positive = np.where(np.isfinite(data) & (data != 0),
                             np.abs(data),
                             10**(significance-1))

    # Align data by magnitude, round, and scale back to original
    magnitude = 10 ** (significance - 1 - np.floor(np.log10(data_positive)))
    data_rounded = np.round(data * magnitude) / magnitude

    # Place back into Series or DataFrame
    if inplace:
        df.loc[:] = data_rounded
    else:
        if isinstance(df, pd.DataFrame):
            return pd.DataFrame(data=data_rounded,
                                index=df.index,
                                columns=df.columns)
        else:
            return pd.Series(data=data_rounded, index=df.index)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simpler vectorized function that should do the job. It can be used directly on a Series or DataFrame.

```
import numpy as np, pandas as pd

def round(x, n_figs):
    power = 10 ** np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(x).clip(1e-200)))
    rounded = np.round(x / power, n_figs - 1) * power
    return rounded


df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": [1234.5678, 0.012345678, 0.0], "b": [1234.5, 0.0012345, 0.0]}
)
print(round(df["a"], 3))
# 0    1230.0000
# 1       0.0123
# 2       0.0000

print(round(df, 3))
#            a           b
# 0  1230.0000  1230.00000
# 1     0.0123     0.00123
# 2     0.0000     0.00000
```

This is how it works:

1. figure out the position of the first digit (anything smaller than 1e-200 will be treated as starting at position -200, to handle 0 without errors)
2. shift the number that many decimal places, so it has exactly 1 digit to the left of the decimal point
3. round to n-1 decimal places
4. shift the number back to the original position