# How to do element-wise rounding of NumPy array to first non-zero digit?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, rounding

I would like to "round" (not exact a mathematical rounding) the elements of a numpy array in the following way:

Given a numpy NxN or NxM 2D array with digit between 0.00001 to 9.99999 like

```
 a=np.array([[1.232, 1.872,2.732,0.123],
             [0.0019, 0.025, 1.854, 0.00017],
             [1.457, 0.0021, 2.34 , 9.99],
             [1.527, 3.3, 0.012 , 0.005]]
    )
```

I would like basically to "round" this numpy array by selecting the first non-zero digit (irregardless of the digit that follows the first non-zero digit) of each element
giving the output:

```
output =np.array([[1.0, 1.0, 2.0, 0.1],
                 [0.001, 0.02, 1.0, 0.0001],
                 [1.0, 0.002, 2 , 9.0],
                 [1, 3, 0.01 , 0.005]]
        )
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: Use numpy.around

Comment: in numpy around does not work properly because the when I set the values numpy.around(a, decimals=0)  the numbers 0.0019 , 0.025 , 0.00017 etc they become all 0 instead of 0.001, 0.02, 0.0001

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rounding to significant figures in numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18915378/rounding-to-significant-figures-in-numpy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get the powers of 10 for each number in the array with

```py
powers = np.floor(np.log10(a))
```

In your example this gives us

```
array([[ 0.,  0.,  0., -1.],
       [-3., -2.,  0., -4.],
       [ 0., -3.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0., -2., -3.]])
```

Now, if we divide the `i`-th element in the array by `10**power_i` we essentially move each number non-zero element in the array to the first position. Now we can simple take the floor to remove the other non-zero digits and then multiply the result by `10**power_i` to get back to the original scale.

The complete solution is then only the code below

```py
powers = np.floor(np.log10(a))
10**powers * np.floor(a/10**powers)
```

### What about numbers greater than or equal to 10?

For this you can simply take `np.floor` of the original value in the array. We can do this easily with a mask. You can modify the answer as below

```py
powers = np.floor(np.log10(a))
result = 10**powers * np.floor(a/10**powers)

mask = a >= 10
result[mask] = np.floor(a[mask])
```

You can also use a mask to avoid computing the powers and logarithm for numbers that will just be replaced later.

Comment: Thanks! works very nice and simple. Is there a way to kind of generalize this procedure with numbers bigger than 10 , let's say if it's 12.32  , 15.78 , 121.34  to get out 12 , 15 , 121?

Comment: Note that here `a` may not have non-positve values.

Comment: I have edited the answer with a section to make it work with numbers >= 10.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `np.logspace` and `np.seachsorted` to determine the order of magnitude of each element and then floor divide and multiply back

```
po10 = np.logspace(-10,10,21)
oom = po10[po10.searchsorted(a)-1]
a//oom*oom
# array([[1.e+00, 1.e+00, 2.e+00, 1.e-01],
#        [1.e-03, 2.e-02, 1.e+00, 1.e-04],
#        [1.e+00, 2.e-03, 2.e+00, 9.e+00],
#        [1.e+00, 3.e+00, 1.e-02, 5.e-03]])
```

Comment: Would this be faster / numerically more stable than just computing the logarithm?

Comment: @norok2 Depends on problem size. The logspace has to be computed only once and since it has only a handful of entries the searchsorted is certainly faster than taking the log and power. You could even push it further and instead of the logspace 10^-10, 10^-9, 10^-8, use all possible outcomes ,i.e. xpo10 = 1 x 10^-10, 2 x 10^-10, 3 x 10^-10, ... 9 x 10^-10, 1 x  10^-9, 2 x 10^-9, etc. That is still a very manageable number of terms and we wouldn't have to do any arithmetic anymore just `xpo10[xpo10.searchsorted(a)-1]`

Answer (score 1):

What you would want to do is to keep a fixed number of [significant figures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

This functionality is not integrated into NumPy.

To get only the 1 significant figure, you could look into either [@PaulPanzer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58531308/5218354) or [@darcamo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58531354/5218354) answers (assuming that you only have positive values).

If you want something that works a specified number of significant figures, you could use something like:

```
def significant_figures(arr, num=1):
    # : compute the order of magnitude
    order = np.zeros_like(arr)  
    mask = arr != 0
    order[mask] = np.floor(np.log10(np.abs(arr[mask])))
    del mask  # free unused memory
    # : compute the corresponding precision
    prec = num - order - 1
    return np.round(arr * 10.0 ** prec) / 10.0 ** prec


print(significant_figures(a, 1))
# [[1.e+00 2.e+00 3.e+00 1.e-01]
#  [2.e-03 2.e-02 2.e+00 2.e-04]
#  [1.e+00 2.e-03 2.e+00 1.e+01]
#  [2.e+00 3.e+00 1.e-02 5.e-03]]

print(significant_figures(a, 2))
# [[1.2e+00 1.9e+00 2.7e+00 1.2e-01]
#  [1.9e-03 2.5e-02 1.9e+00 1.7e-04]
#  [1.5e+00 2.1e-03 2.3e+00 1.0e+01]
#  [1.5e+00 3.3e+00 1.2e-02 5.0e-03]]
```

---

## EDIT

For truncated output use `np.floor()` instead of `np.round()` just before the `return`.

Comment: Small nitpick: OP says "round" but what they really do is truncate, i.e. always round down / towards zero.

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks for spotting this! Fixed.