# round exponential float to 2 decimals

Tags: python, rounding, exponential

I want to round exponential float to two decimal representation in Python.

```
4.311237638482733e-91 --> 4.31e-91
```

Do you know any quick trick to do that?
Simple solutions like `round(float, 2)` and `"%.2f"%float` are not working with exponential floats:/

**EDIT:**
It's not about rounding float, but rounding exponential float, thus it's not the same question as [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python)

Comment: `"%.3g" % 4.311237638482733e-91  --> '4.31e-91'` `f` is *not* the only way to format a float. see [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting). Also `str.format` is more powerful.

Comment: `format(4.311237638482733e-91, '.2e')`??

Comment: @Bakuriu I'm happy to accept your comment as an answer, but you will need to write it as the answer;)

Comment: @Leszek I didn't answer immediately because the question was closed as duplicate, and I didn't want to reopen it immediately before further checking... and then I forgot about it :)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `g` format specifier, which chooses between the exponential and the "usual" notation based on the precision, and specify the number of significant digits:

```
>>> "%.3g" % 4.311237638482733e-91
'4.31e-91'
```

If you want to always represent the number in exponential notation use the `e` format specifier, while `f` *never* uses the exponential notation. The full list of possibilities is described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting).

Also note that instead of `%`-style formatting you could use `str.format`:

```
>>> '{:.3g}'.format(4.311237638482733e-91)
'4.31e-91'
```

`str.format` is more powerful and customizable than `%`-style formatting, and it is also more consistent. For example:

```
>>> '' % []
''
>>> '' % set()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting
>>> ''.format([])
''
>>> ''.format(set())
''
```

If you don't like calling a method on a string literal you can use the [`format`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#format) built-in function:

```
>>> format(4.311237638482733e-91, '.3g')
'4.31e-91'
```