# How to round float down to 3 decimal places?

Tags: python, floating-point

I wrote a function to return the energy of a given wavelength. When I run the function the print statement returns the float `E`, but returns 20+ decimals and I cannot figure out how to round it down.

```
def FindWaveEnergy(color, lam):
  c = 3.0E8
  V = c/lam
  h = 6.626E-34
  E = h*V
  print("The energy of the " + color.lower() + " wave is " + str(E) + "J.")
FindWaveEnergy("red", 6.60E-7)
```

I tried doing this:

```
def FindWaveEnergy(color, lam):
  c = 3.0E8
  V = c/lam
  h = 6.626E-34
  E = h*V
  print("The energy of the " + color.lower() + " wave is " + str('{:.2f}'.format(E)) + "J.")
FindWaveEnergy("red", 6.60E-7)
```

But that returned `0.000000J`.
How can I fix my program to return 3 decimal places?

The program returns an E value. i.e. `3.10118181818181815e-19J`.
I want it to return something like `3.1012e-19J` with fewer decimal places.

Comment: Give a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9232256/round-up-to-second-decimal-place-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are actually nearly there.
I found this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118366/round-exponential-float-to-2-decimals)

So all you have to do is change

`str('{:.2f}'.format(E))`

to

`str('{:.3g}'.format(E))`

Comment: No need for the `str` wrapper: the format call result is already string, so `'{:.3g}'.format(E)` is enough. (You could also spell this more concisely as `format(E, '.3g')`, but in the OP's context there's surrounding text, so it make sense to use the string interpolation facility of `format` in place of all the string additions.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def FindWaveEnergy(color, lam):
  c = 3.0E8
  V = c/lam
  h = 6.626E-34
  E = str(h*V).split("e")
  print("The energy of the " + color.lower() + " wave is " + E[0][:4] + "e" + E[-1] + "J.")
FindWaveEnergy("red", 6.60E-7)
```

or you can :

```
print("The energy of the " + color.lower() + " wave is " + str('{:.2e}'.format(E)) + "J.")
```