# How to round fractional coefficient with f-string

Tags: python, printing, f-string

After carrying a `Chi2` test on some contingency table (using: `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency(myTable)`) I get some statistics:

```
stat=215.87297677691768
p=1.6223014100068392e-27
dof=36
```

I then print these results using the `f-string` formatting:

```
new_line = '\n'
print(
        f'Chi2 value = {stat:.4f}{new_line}'
        f'p-value = {p}{new_line}'
        f'Degrees of freedom = {dof}{new_line}'
    )
```

This gives me the output:

```
Chi2 value = 215.8730
p-value = 1.6223014100068392e-27
Degrees of freedom = 36
```

Is it possible to modify something in the `p-value` `f-string` in order to have the fractional coefficient of the `p-value` printed with 4 digits and so get the output:

```
Chi2 value = 215.8730
p-value = 1.6223e-27
Degrees of freedom = 36
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [round exponential float to 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24118366/round-exponential-float-to-2-decimals)

Comment: The link in the comment above already covers it.  Simply change `{p}` to `{p:.5g}`

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of the `g` possibility in `{**: .5g}` for example... Perfect!