# Python general number formatting behaviour

Tags: python

I'm using the general formatting option to print floats as strings, but i find the behaviour somewhat unusual.  For example, when specifying a precision (number of digits following the decimal point):
For float format:

```
In [1]: '%f' % 123.456
Out[1]: '123.456000'

In [2]: '%.1f' % 123.456
Out[2]: '123.5'
```

works just as expected.  Now, compare this to:

```
In [3]: '%g' % 123.456
Out[3]: '123.456'

In [4]: '%.1g' % 123.456
Out[4]: '1e+02'
```

Or even worse:

```
In [6]: '%5g' % 123.456
Out[6]: '123.456'

In [7]: '%.5g' % 123.456
Out[7]: '123.46'
```

It seems to be taking the "precision" value to mean "width".  Is this a bug, or is it expected behaviour?

Ps.  What I want is to print floating point numbers (up to a given precision) with the minimum needed characters.  For example:  0.301238 with precision 1 prints as 0.3; 100.0003 with precision 1 prints as 100;

Comment: As a note, it's [generally recommended](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#printf-style-string-formatting) to use the more powerful and easier to read [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#format) method over `%` formatting in Python.

Comment: Roger that, just used the % formatting for readability in the example.  Using `format()` gives you the same behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The formatting spec](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) states:

> The precision is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be
>   displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted
>   with 'f' and 'F', **or before and after the decimal point for a floating
>   point value formatted with 'g' or 'G'**. For non-number types the field
>   indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters
>   will be used from the field content. The precision is not allowed for
>   integer values.

(Emphasis added)

This is the expected behaviour.

I don't believe there is a way to get one significant digit (what you appear to want) using only string formatting. [Manually manipulating the number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411435/722121) would be required.

```
>>> from math import log10, floor
>>> def round_to_1(x):
...    return round(x, -int(floor(log10(x))))
...
>>> "{:g}".format(round_to_1(0.301238))
0.3
>>> "{:g}".format(round_to_1(100.0003))
100
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for this solution! You can add arbitrary precision by using `lambda n,p :'{:g}'.format(round(n, p))`

Answer (score 0):

I think your requirement "with the minimum needed characters" is the problem, since you get `1e+02` instead of `100` and `1e+01` instead of `10`.

You could do something silly like this if the number is >= 9.5:

```
>>> str(int(float("{:.1g}".format(123.4567))))
'100'
```

Otherwise:

```
>>> "{:.1g}".format(9.4321)
'9'
>>> "{:.1g}".format(0.1234567)
'0.1'
```