# Pass value in the text of plt.text function

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is the abstracted problem, every time `lst` is different, so I want to do it automatically

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
fig=plt.figure()
fig.set_size_inches(8,4)
lst=np.array ([0.1235,0.2322,0.3300]) 
#how can I directly pass these value to plt.text, without manually input
plt.text(0.05,0.6,r'a=0.124,  b=0.232,  c=0.330',fontsize=18)
plt.show()
```

Comment: str.format? https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: What do you exactly trying to do? Give example input/output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `str.format()` and pass in the list as the parameter to it (and use indexes inside `{}` to determine where and with what format a element goes , Example -

```
plt.text(0.05,0.6,r'a={0:.3f}, b={1:.3f}, c={2:.3f}'.format(*lst),fontsize=18)
```

The number before `:` is the index of the element which needs to be substituted there, and the `.3f` denotes it will have 3 places after decimal , and f is for float.

Please note, above will not round the number (a would be printed with - `a=0.123`) , if you want the number rounded as well , you cna use list comprehension with round function -

```
plt.text(0.05,0.6,r'a={0:.3f}, b={1:.3f}, c={2:.3f}'.format(*[round(x,3) for x in lst]),fontsize=18)
```

Comment: What if I want to keep three effective digits(need also round)? For example, lst=[0.01234, 0.0001345, 0.00000015678].

Comment: last two would be 0.000 even if your round and keep three digits. For round and three effective digits use the second one i pasted.

Comment: The second you passed also give 0.000, which is not three effective digits. I need 0.000000157 for the last one, say.

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python Many thanks for your answer as well.