# Python - How to round down a float to 1 significant digit

Tags: python, floating-point

I want to round down a float to a specific number of significant digits. Very similar to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411435/281021  but instead of the normal `round()` behavior, it should round down always. I can't use `math.floor()` because it turns the float into an int.

Basically, `0.45` should become `0.4` instead of `0.5`.
And `1945.01` should become `1000.0` instead of `2000.0`.

Comment: if its not actually a dupe of that question let me know and i will flag reopen

Comment: @JoranBeasley It's not a dupe of that.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. He does not want to do `1999 -> 2000` but rather `1999->1000`

Comment: `def floor(number, pos): return float(int(number * (10**pos)) / (10**pos))` and then `floor(0.45, 1)` -> `0.4` , `floor(1945.01, -3)` -> `1000.0`

Comment: sorry ... reopened

Comment: man now i really feel like a jerk (thats even the answer he mentioned) very sorry @Albert

Comment: What about negative numbers? `-1111` rounds down to `-2000`?

Comment: This was a similar question, with a slight twist. No worries @JoranBeasley :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scientific representation seems to be the way to go, but numerical techniques usually end up faster for me than string techniques. You do get the occasional floating point error however...

```
from math import *


def roundDown(x, sigfigs=1): #towards -inf 
    exponent = floor(log10(copysign(x,1))) #we don't want to accidentally try and get an imaginary log (it won't work anyway)
    mantissa = x/10**exponent #get full precision mantissa
    # change floor here to ceil or round to round up or to zero
    mantissa = floor(mantissa * 10**(sigfigs-1)) / 10**(sigfigs-1) #round mantissa to sigfigs
    return mantissa * 10**exponent
```

Rounding towards zero or +inf is as easy as changing the `floor` to `ceil` or `round`. Another benefit of computing the mantissa and exponent numerically rather than casting to a string is that the number of sigfigs can be easily changed

Comment: This will fail in the extreme case, e.g. `roundDown(decimal.Decimal('1.99999999999999999999999999999'))`, but I guess it works with floats.

Comment: even floats are subject to floating point error: `roundDown(15.64, 3)` -> 
`15.600000000000001`

Comment: Thanks! Changing `floor` on line 5 to `ceil` to round up works, but changing it to `round` makes it round _from zero_, not _to zero_: `roundZero(2.57) == 2.6, roundZero(-2.57) == -2.6`. How to make it round to zero?

Answer (score 0):

Use scientific notion to take the significant digit and the power, and calculate the result

```
def significant_1 (s):
    l = len(str(s))   ####make sure there is enough precision
    a = ('%.' + str(l) + 'E') % decimal.Decimal(s)
    #print (a)
    significate_d = a.split(".")[0]
    times = a.split("E")[1]

    result = int(significate_d) * (10 ** int(times))

    return result


print (significant_1(1999))

print (significant_1(1945.01))

print (significant_1(0.45))
```

output:

```
1000
1000
0.4
```

Comment: `significant_1(1999)` returns `2000`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a good and simple way:

```
def convert(number, interval):
    return int(number/interval)*interval
```

Sample outputs:

```
1923,1000 -> 1000
12.45,0.1 -> 12.4
```

Comment: In this case, the user needs to specify the interval every time. The question only needs the first significant digit and the power.

Comment: I think the question must be more clear. because I couldn't understand why 1945.1 is converted to 1000. and not 1900 or 1940!

Answer (score 0):

One approach to formatting floats is to use string formatting, then convert them back to floats. This isn't likely as CPU-efficient as other approaches, but it requires only minimal coding:

```
>>> from math import sqrt
>>> x = sqrt(2)
>>> x
1.4142135623730951
>>> float("%g" % x)
1.41421
>>> float("%.2g" % x)
1.4
>>> float("%.3g" % x)
1.41
```

Obviously the additional digits are lost, not recoverable:

```
>>> u = float("%.2g" % x)
>>> float("%.5f" % u)
1.4
>>> float("%.5g" % u)
1.4
```

Answer (score -2):

```
 round(number[, ndigits])
```

Return the floating point value number rounded to ndigits digits after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted, it defaults to zero. The result is a floating point number. Values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits; if two multiples are equally close, rounding is done away from 0 (so, for example, round(0.5) is 1.0 and round(-0.5) is -1.0).

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round

Comment: That doesn't round 1945.01 to 1000.0, does it?

Comment: He wants this always rounded down. `round(0.5)` should give `0` in this scenario.