# Exponential to Float (Getting ALL decimal numbers of Float)

Tags: python

I need to get ALL decimal numbers possible, but I have a limit of 19 number char on the spinbox. Setting a static numbers on how many decimal places will be and setting a static number of decimals (setDecimals()) is not acceptable since the value I am getting is dynamic.

For example, I want to convert Hertz:

Hertz: 1.00
Megahertz: 1e-6
GigaHertz: 1e-9

I want it to be in this format:
1.00,
0.000006,
0.000000009,

Yes! Decimal places are dynamic.

This is the code for conversion (Value of dictionary is not yet finished):

`conversion_formula = {'Hz': 1, 'kHz': 1e-3, 'MHz': 1e-6, 'GHz': 1e-9,
                      's': 1, 'ms': 1e-3, 'us': 1e-6, 'ns': 1e-9,
                      'V': 1, 'mV': 1e-3}`

```
if FREQUENCY_UNIT_NAME == title or AMPLITUDE_UNIT_NAME == title:
    output_value = input_value * (conversion_formula[current_unit] / conversion_formula[base_unit])
elif title == TIME_UNIT_NAME:
    output_value = input_value * (conversion_formula[base_unit] / conversion_formula[current_unit])
```

Comment: 1e-9 and 0.000000009 are the same number, just written in a different way. Are you asking how to `print` in one format or the other?

Comment: in 0.000000009 format. Because when I print the number, it's in 1e-9

Comment: All decimal places? Really? What if the value is e.g. π, or even something simpler, like 1/3?

Comment: I have a number char limit on the spinbox, up to 19.

Comment: `'%.19f' % x` formats float numbers to 19 digits

Comment: But the decimals will be set to max. As much as possible, I'm looking for value like (0.000076, 0.23, 0.000000000432)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python package [`to-precision`](https://bitbucket.org/william_rusnack/to-precision) does the job, as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44134235/4791226).