# Round a number off to 3 sig figs python

Tags: python

I am trying to write a program for a physics lab that can round off a function to 3 sig figs. I have tried using the round function and other methods mentioned in the other post, but it does not work. The answer to the other question only covers 1 sig fig, not 3. I need it to float when it rounds off numbers. For example, 0.4324 rounds to .432, 0.0002443 rounds to .000244, and 132300 rounds to 132000.
I don't want it to print the value, but instead round it and then store it in a variable, as I need it to be rounded off at intermediate steps

```
 m = float(input("Enter mass: "))
a = float(input("Enter acceleration: "))
i = m*a         
n = 3
print('{:g}'.format(float('{:.3g}'.format(i))))
```

that is the program I wrote to calculate force to 3 sig figs.
This is the output

```
Enter mass: 4523
Enter acceleration: 2345
1.06e+07
```

Comment: you mean like 47.534534 to 47.535?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python) - in particular the answer by [indgar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3413529/12366110) or [Falken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812729/12366110)

Comment: This question does not answer it

Comment: ranifisch, this is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: What specific difficulties do you have with the answers there?

Comment: It also covers using another package, which I cannot install. I tried using the round_to_3 function, but it gave me a name error

Comment: `round(0.0002443, 6)`? It yields `Out[1]: 0.000244` like you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python/3411731#3411731), you can use `float('%.3g' % i)`. This gives a float (which gets automatically converted to string if you print it).

If you want to dynamically control the number of digits, you can introduce a little function that first creates a formatting string.

Some tests:

```py
def round_to_n_digits(num, n=3):
    formatstr = '%.'+str(n)+'g'
    return float(formatstr % num)

i = 4523*2345
print(float('%.3g' % i))

a = [round_to_n_digits(4523*2345, 5),
     round_to_n_digits(123456789),
     round_to_n_digits(0.0002443),
     round_to_n_digits(0.4324)]
print (a)
```

Output:

```
10600000.0
[10606000.0, 123000000.0, 0.000244, 0.432]
```

Answer (score 0):

For 3 s.f.:

```
>>> print('{:g}'.format(float('{:.3g}'.format(12.345))))
12.3
```

From [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812729/12366110)

Comment: It gives me an answer in scientific notation, when I need it in standard notattion