# Round to a number that is not zero

Tags: python, rounding

In python you have `round(number, digits)`.

I have numbers like

```
0.123525,
0.01346346,
0.0078236346,
3.43568
...
```

My goal is for `round` to round up to the first digit that is not zero

ie

```
0.1
0.01
0.008
3
...
```

My pseudocode-approach:

```
convert double to string
for each literal in string check whether it's zero
once it's not, count digits
use digits for digits in round.
```

Is there a ready made function or an elegant approach?

Comment: `1 - math.log10(n)` gives the number of digits to round to, I think (not extensively tested).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python)

Comment: `0.1` is actually a bad example. You cannot store `0.1` (*exactly*) in a floating point number, it's always going to be either `0.09999...` or `0.1000...[not-0]`.

Comment: It is better to use `decimal.Decimal` .  Dealing string becomes difficult when number has exponent like 0.12E-32

Answer (score 4):

For a variable x with a value between 1e-4 and 9, a simple way is

- `f'{x:.1g}'` as a string
- `float(f'{x:.1g}'`) as a float.

For example:

```
>>> x = 0.002345
>>> print(f'{x:.1g}')
0.002
```

See [python format specification](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) for explanation. Briefly, the an f-string `f'{x}'` converts a variable to string; the `:.1g` is a format specifier, with `.1` indicating the number of significant digits and `g` indicating that it tries to make a human-friendly representation if possible: rather 0.001 than 1E-03 but 1E-05 rather than 0.00001 because in the latter case, the zeros become hard to count and it takes more space than 1E-05.

Comment: I added explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
import math

def r(n):
    k = 1 - int(math.log10(n))
    return round(n, None if n > 1 else k)

>>> [r(n) for n in [0.123525, 0.01346346, 0.0078236346, 3.43568]]
[0.1, 0.01, 0.008, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting to a string and back, you could multiply the number by 10 and keep track of how many times you have to do this before the value is over 1.0.

Example:

0.005869
Times 10
0.05869
*loop*
0.5869
*loop*
5.869
*break*

You looped 3 times (multiplied the value by 10^3), so you can call

```
round(0.005869, 3) = 0.006
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you typically expect: how long are these numbers and are they normal numbers, or mostly tiny ones with lots and lots of zeroes?

Also, how do you get these numbers: are they all in float type variables? Do you read them from a text file?

Assuming you have floats:

```
import math


def to_first(number):
    log10 = math.log(number, 10)
    return number if log10 > 0 else round(number, math.floor(1-log10))


examples = [0.0001, 0.123, 4.3, 0.010000, 0.19]

for x in examples:
    print(f'{x}: {to_first(x)}')
```

The key of course is `math.log(x, 10)` - the answer basically tells you what to do and the `to_first` function does just that.

Note that `0.19` becomes `0.2`, not `0.1`. I'd assume that's desired behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
numbers = [0.123525,0.01346346,0.0078236346,3.43568]
d = [len(str(num).split('.')[1])-len(str(num).split('.')[1].lstrip('0')) for num in numbers]
numbers2 = [round(n,num+1) if num else int(num) for n,num in zip(numbers,d)]
print(numbers2)
```

Output:

```
[0, 0.01, 0.008, 3]
```

---

---

For more clarity:

```
numbers = [0.123525,0.01346346,0.0078236346,3.43568]
numbers2 = []

for num in numbers:

    dec_digits = str(num).split('.')[1] # all decimal digits of the number in a string

    r = len(dec_digits)-len(dec_digits.lstrip('0')) # the amount of zeros on the left side of the string

    if r: # if the number of zeros is greater than 0:
        numbers2.append(round(num,r+1))
    else:
        numbers2.append(int(num))

print(numbers2)
```