# Round to two places (not decimal places) python

Tags: python, rounding

How can I round to two places - not decimal places?

ex.

```
input: 2.6759, 3.5632, 30.8736, 42.8927
output: 2.7, 3.6, 31, 43
```

Comment: "significant figures" is the keyword you're looking for

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python) Specifically this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48812729/843953

Answer (score 1):

```
import math

def roundx(v):
    scale = int(math.log10(v))
    x = int(v * 10**(1-scale) + 0.5) * 10**(scale-1)
    return x

for v in (2.6759,3.5632,30.8736,42.8927):
    print(roundx(v))
```

Output:

```
2.7
3.6
31
43
```

Comment: Or just `f"{x:.2g}"`

Comment: That fails with 123.456, for example. "Fails" may be too harsh; it prints `1.2e+02`, which is unexpected.