# Plotly log scale show full tick values

Tags: python, plotly

Consider [the code in the example](https://plotly.com/python/log-plot/) which is

```
import plotly.express as px
df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", hover_name="country", log_x=True)
fig.show()
```

and produces

[image]

Is it possible that the ticks in the `x` axis would show `2000`, `20k` and so on instead of `2`, and the same for `3`, `4` ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- you can use https://plotly.com/python/tick-formatting/#tickmode--array
- below example takes into account it's geometric and only want one significant digit in axis [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python)

```
import plotly.express as px
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2007")

fig = px.scatter(df, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", hover_name="country", log_x=True)
fig.update_layout(
    xaxis={
        "tickmode": "array",
        "tickvals": pd.to_numeric(
            [f"{n:.1g}" for n in np.geomspace(1, df["gdpPercap"].max(), 15)]
        ),
    }
)
```

[image]