# How to show full number in plotly log scale

Tags: python, plotly

I want to add this:

[image]

I.e. the multiplier `f` (for *femto* in this case) to every tick, not only the powers of 10, as is the case already for linear scale. Is it possible to change this behavior?

I would prefer an answer that fixes this automatically by changing the behavior of Plotly, don't want to modify every tick manually.

Comment: There is a related answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69961914/377366 but it seems no native way in plotly.

Comment: @KobeJohn unfortunately no. All "solutions" imply manually adding the multipliers.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to modify both the minor and major ticks. Right now nothing's built into Plotly's API to modify the minor tick formatting. However, I found a creative workaround.

You didn't share any programming code. I don't know if you're using a notebook or Plotly express, go, or Plotly as a backend. I don't know how your data is structured or how you called the axis to be log-scaled. That being said, without that information it's difficult to give you a solution that will regardless of what you're working with. (It's always better to share your programming code on a programming forum.)

This uses a Plotly example graph, go, and io. When I use the function `io.write_html` you may notice that I called several defaults to the defaults. I have to say that the Plotly documentation must not be up to date. The listed defaults are not necessarily defaulted.

This calls for a graph, and Javascript then combines the two into an HTML file that will automatically render in your default browser.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.io as io

df = px.data.gapminder().query("year == 2002")
fig = px.scatter(df, x = "gdpPercap", y = "lifeExp", hover_name = "country", log_x = True)

js = '''
setTimeout(function() {
    that = document.querySelectorAll('svg g.xtick')
    that.forEach(el => el.firstChild.innerHTML = el.firstChild.innerHTML + ' f')
}, 200)
'''
io.write_html(fig = fig, file = "fig2.html", post_script = js, 
              full_html = True, include_plotlyjs = 'cdn', auto_open = True)
```

This reflects a `10k f` which is something I doubt anyone would be looking for. However, it doesn't look like your data has that.

[image]