# How to round certain values in list

Tags: python

I have a list in Python

```
a = [100.50, 121.50, 130.50, 140.50, 150.50, 160.50, 170.50, 180.50, 190.50, 200.50]
```

I want to round first three values

```
 [100.00, 100.00, 100.00, 140.50, 150.50, 160.50, 170.50, 180.50, 190.50, 200.50]
```

I need to round down to 100.0 if they are < 130.0 and then similarly round down to 200 if they are < 230 and so on.

Comment: with for loop and if conditions

Comment: Should the first 3 entries in your list be `100.00, 100.00, 100.00` or `100.00, 122.00, 130.00`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on comments it seems you want to round down to 100.0 if they are < 130.0 and then similarly round down to 200 if they are < 230 and so on.

So the following:

```
b = [100*(x//100) if x % 100 < 30 else x for x in a]
```

So for every element `x` of list `a`, if the remainder of dividing it by 100 is less than 30 we have to round it down other wise keep `x`.

For rounding down to 100, 200, ... integer divide `x` by 100 and then multiply again by 100.

**Example**

```
a = [100.50, 121.50, 130.50, 220.50, 240.50, 310.50, 350.50]
```

**Output**

```
    [100.0, 100.0,   130.5,  200.0,  240.5,  300.0,  350.5]
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir!
That's exactly what I need!

Comment: @user18560399 This was completely different from your original question. Please try to write clear questions. This should have been a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Slice the list, apply `round()`, re-assign the list:

```
>>> a[:3] = map(round, a[:3])
>>> a
[100, 122, 130, 140.5, 150.5, 160.5, 170.5, 180.5, 190.5, 200.5]
```

Note, I'm assuming you want to round the values and not make them all 100. Otherwise, you can use a function [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python):

```
>>> from math import log10, floor
>>> def round_to_1(x):
...     return round(x, -int(floor(log10(abs(x)))))
... 
>>> a[:3] = list(map(round_to_1, a[:3]))
>>> a
[100.0, 100.0, 100.0, 140.5, 150.5, 160.5, 170.5, 180.5, 190.5, 200.5]
```

Comment: For some reason they want to round the first three elements down to 100 apparently . Look at the expected output! (unless it's a typo)

Comment: Thats good, thanks but what if these numbers are in random order 
[100.50, 200.50, 121.50, 140.50, 130.50, 150.50, 160.50, 180.50, 190.50, 170.50]
I still need them to to round down to 100.0 if they are < 130.0
And not by index cause I want same with 200.0 till 230.0, 300. till 330 etc

Comment: @user18560399 that's a completely different question! You should update your question

Comment: @user18560399 see my answer. But consider updating your question for other people

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> def round_first_n(arr, n):
...     for i in range(n):
...             arr[i] = round(arr[i])
...
>>> arr = [100.5]*10
>>> arr
[100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5]
>>> round_first_n(arr, 3)
>>> arr
[100, 100, 100, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5, 100.5]
```

To round at arbitrary indices:

```
>>> def round_at(arr, indices):
...     for i in indices:
...             arr[i] = round(arr[i])
...
>>> round_at(arr, [5,7])
>>> arr
[100, 100, 100, 100.5, 100.5, 100, 100.5, 100, 100.5, 100.5]
```

Comment: You might want to add bounds checking ;) (since if n > len(arr) -1) you will get an "out of bounds" error, since you'd be accessing an index of the array that does not exist)