# How to format floating-point number to x significant digits

Tags: python, string, floating-point

I am looking to print a floating-point number to a number of significant digits, where I consider digits in front of the decimal separator as significant. So with 3 significant digits, I would like the following:

```
1234.56 --> 1235  # edited that - I think 1234 is not what I want here
123.456 --> 123
12.3456 --> 12.3
1.23456 --> 1.23
.123456 --> 0.123
.012345 --> 0.0123
.0012345 --> 0.00123
```

Basically, I want to suppress the decimal fraction if it is not required, but I do not want to round the integer part. (And I would like to avoid scientific notation.)

How can I achieve that? I tried a number of ways, but none really do what I want.

This is close, but uses scientific notation:

```
for x in [1234.56, 123.456, 12.3456, 1.23456, .123456, .012345, .0012345]:
    print(x, " --> ", f"{x:.3g}")

1234.56  -->  1.23e+03  # wrong!
123.456  -->  123
12.3456  -->  12.3
1.23456  -->  1.23
0.123456  -->  0.123
0.012345  -->  0.0123
0.0012345  -->  0.00123
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python)

Comment: @TheThonnu I should have noted that I would not like to round the integer part - 1234.56 should remain 1234, not 1000 as in the other question.

Comment: @bers it is pretty abnormal to round to N significant digits but to consider all digits in the integer part significant. I am curious why you want to do this.

Comment: @Jagerber48 basically, because I am not interested in conveying some relative measurement uncertainty. The underlying values I am displaying are exact. And people reading these numbers are used to insignificant digits being truncated, but not to insignificant digits being replaced by 0. Writing 1234 as 1000 would be as incorrect as writing 1.234 as 1.000, and I think everyone agrees that 1.000 conveys a false sense of accuracy.

Comment: @bers Well here we're talking about 3 significant digits so 1234 would be changed to 1230. Would you accept 1234 -> 1230 (as opposed to 1.23e+03)? Surely your readers understand that 0.123 = 0.123000 so that they could understand truncation below the decimal point to be the same as replacement of insignificant digits below the decimal point by 0?

Comment: I would also suggest a move away from using significant digits to convey a sense of precision. If you really want to communicate precision then you should explicitly specify an uncertainty. e.g. 0.123 +/- 0.001 or 1230 +/- 10. As you have roughly grasped, there is ambiguity when it comes to specifying uncertainty using sig figs for numbers greater than 1. Is 1200 supposed to be 1200 +/- 100? or 1200 +/- 1? To avoid this ambiguity you need to explicitly specify.

Comment: @Jagerber48 "Would you accept 1234 -> 1230 (as opposed to 1.23e+03)." No, for the same reason that I would not accept "1.230e+03" (if I did accept scientific notation to begin with).

Comment: @Jagerber48 "I would also suggest a move away from using significant digits to convey a sense of precision." Agreed. I am not referring to "precision" anywhere. This is purely to limit the length of the printed output, yet without "falsifying" information (and without resorting to scientific notation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works nicely:

```py
import numpy as np

MIN_DIGITS = 0
SIGN_DIGITS = 3

for x in [1234.56, 123.456, 12.3456, 1.23456, 0.123456, 0.012345, 0.0012345]:
    print(
        x,
        "-->",
        np.format_float_positional(
            x,
            precision=max(SIGN_DIGITS - int(np.ceil(np.log10(x))), MIN_DIGITS),
            trim="-",
        ),
    )
```

```
1234.56 --> 1235
123.456 --> 123
12.3456 --> 12.3
1.23456 --> 1.23
0.123456 --> 0.123
0.012345 --> 0.0123
0.0012345 --> 0.00123
```

And with `MIN_DIGITS = 1`:

```
1234.56 --> 1234.6
123.456 --> 123.5
12.3456 --> 12.3
1.23456 --> 1.23
0.123456 --> 0.123
0.012345 --> 0.0123
0.0012345 --> 0.00123
```

Answer (score 1):

In such conditions you can try like this

```
for f in [1234.56, 123.456, 12.3456, 1.23456, .123456, .012345, .0012345]:

    dp= str(f)[::-1].find('.')
    #print(dp)
    if dp <=3:

        fs= int(f)
        print(f, "-->",fs)
    else:
        print(f, " --> ", f"{f:.3g}")
```

output:

```
1234.56 --> 1234
123.456 --> 123
12.3456  -->  12.3
1.23456  -->  1.23
0.123456  -->  0.123
0.012345  -->  0.0123
0.0012345  -->  0.00123
```

Comment: This uses scientific notation for 
`f = 0.00000123`, but maybe I just need to accept that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers the OP, but I have a PyPi package I have written that may help address this problem called [sciform](https://sciform.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). `sciform` is meant to take numbers and format them into strings according to scientific formatting rules including rounding by sig figs. The output strings can be converted back to numbers if desired in some cases.

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    round_mode="sig_fig",  # This is the default behavior
    ndigits=3,
)

num_list = [
    1234.56,
    123.456,
    12.3456,
    1.23456,
    0.123456,
    0.0123456,
    0.00123456
]

for num in num_list:
    result = sform(num)
    print(f'{num} --> {result}')
    
# 1234.56 --> 1230
# 123.456 --> 123
# 12.3456 --> 12.3
# 1.23456 --> 1.23
# 0.123456 --> 0.123
# 0.0123456 --> 0.0123
# 0.00123456 --> 0.00123
```

Note that this converts 1234.56 to 1230 instead of 1235 as specified in the OP. The request in the OP would be strange with respect to standard scientific formatting rules, but I present this answer anyways.

The strange request to perform rounding below the decimal may come from misconceptions about using significant figures to communicate uncertainty. Below the decimal point this can be done unambiguously. Above the decimal point this is impossible because there is always ambiguity. If I see the number 12300 do I interpret it as 12300 +/- 100, 12300 +/- 10, or 12300 +/- 1? All three could be valid, there is no way to know. Instead, I suggest to accurately communicate uncertainty it must be explicitly specified.

`sciform` also supports formatting value/uncertainty pairs to more explicitly specify uncertainty in a presented quantity.

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    round_mode="sig_fig",  # This is the default behavior
    ndigits=1,  # Now we will round the *uncertainty* to one significant figure
)

num_unc_list = [
    (1234.56, 10),
    (123.456, 1),
    (12.3456, 0.1),
    (1.23456, 0.01),
    (0.123456, 0.001),
    (0.0123456, 0.0001),
    (0.00123456, 0.00001),
]

for num, unc in num_unc_list:
    result = sform(num, unc)
    print(f'({num}, {unc}) --> {result}')

# (1234.56, 10) --> 1230 ± 10
# (123.456, 1) --> 123 ± 1
# (12.3456, 0.1) --> 12.3 ± 0.1
# (1.23456, 0.01) --> 1.23 ± 0.01
# (0.123456, 0.001) --> 0.123 ± 0.001
# (0.0123456, 0.0001) --> 0.0123 ± 0.0001
# (0.00123456, 1e-05) --> 0.00123 ± 0.00001
```

Or a more concise value/uncertainty representation:

```
from sciform import Formatter

sform = Formatter(
    round_mode="sig_fig",  # This is the default behavior
    ndigits=1,  # Now we will round the *uncertainty* to one significant figure
    paren_uncertainty=True
)

num_unc_list = [
    (1234.56, 10),
    (123.456, 1),
    (12.3456, 0.1),
    (1.23456, 0.01),
    (0.123456, 0.001),
    (0.0123456, 0.0001),
    (0.00123456, 0.00001),
]

for num, unc in num_unc_list:
    result = sform(num, unc)
    print(f'({num}, {unc}) --> {result}')

# (1234.56, 10) --> 1230(10)
# (123.456, 1) --> 123(1)
# (12.3456, 0.1) --> 12.3(1)
# (1.23456, 0.01) --> 1.23(1)
# (0.123456, 0.001) --> 0.123(1)
# (0.0123456, 0.0001) --> 0.0123(1)
# (0.00123456, 1e-05) --> 0.00123(1)
```