# python downwards truncation

Tags: python

Is there a simple way to fix this that doesn't involve excessive conditionals? As I would like to generalize this function to *t* digits later on.

```
def three_digit_trunc(num):
    num_str = str(num)
    decimal_index = num_str.find('.')
    
    # Find the index of the first non-zero digit
    non_zero_index = next((i for i, digit in enumerate(num_str) if digit != '0' and digit != '.'), None)
    
    if non_zero_index is not None:
        if decimal_index != -1:
            # Keep the first non-zero digit and its two neighbors to the right
            trunc_index = min(len(num_str), non_zero_index + 3)
            trunc_num = num_str[:chop_index] + '0' * (len(num_str) - trunc_index - 4)
        else:
            # If there is no decimal point, keep the first non-zero digit and its two neighbors to the right
            trunc_index = min(len(num_str), non_zero_index + 3)
            trunc_num = num_str[:chop_index]
    else:
        # If all digits are zero, return 0.0
        trunc_num = '0.0'
    
    return float(trunc_num)
```

Comment: You show some sample outputs. What should the correct output be for the two middle cases?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round a number to significant figures in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410976/how-to-round-a-number-to-significant-figures-in-python)

Comment: @quamrana Just updated to show expected output. 12.3456 -> 12.3, 1.2345 -> 1.23 (3 digit chopping so everything two indices after first non-zero element is zeroed out)

Comment: @SamMason no, since I want to chop as opposed to rounding. math.trunc() also doesn't make sense for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: What about negative numbers?

Comment: @akx thanks for catching that--it chops to two digits for negative numbers because of the additional minus sign in the string.

Comment: What about numbers whose `str` is in scientific notation? That could easily happen with numerical methods which produce numbers close to 0 rather than 0 itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the more efficient and faster way is to use built-in functions as they are generally better:

```py
def three_digit_chop(num):
    abs_num = abs(num)
    if abs_num < 1e-2:
        return round(num, 5)
    elif abs_num < 1e-1:
        return round(num, 4)
    elif abs_num < 1:
        return round(num, 3)
    elif abs_num < 10:
        return round(num, 2)
    elif abs_num < 100:
        return round(num, 1)
    else:
        return round(num)
```

Answer (score 0):

Feels pretty hacky and I'm not sure what you actually want this for, but for your test cases (+ 1 negative one) this yields the right result (and is generalized for any `n`):

```
def three_digit_chop(num, n=3):
    sign = -1 if num < 0 else 1
    num_str = str(abs(num))
    decimal_index = num_str.find(".")
    if decimal_index == -1:  # no decimal part
        return float(num_str[:n]) * sign
    i, _, f = num_str.partition(".")
    if i == "0":  # no integer part, so adjust n accordingly
        n += 1
    num_list = list((i + f)[:n])
    num_list.insert(decimal_index, ".")
    return float("".join(num_list)) * sign


print(three_digit_chop(123))  # correct output: 123.0
print(three_digit_chop(123.456))  # correct output: 123.0
print(three_digit_chop(12.3456))  # should be 12.3
print(three_digit_chop(1.2345))  # should be 1.23
print(three_digit_chop(0.12345))  # Correct Output: 0.12300
print(three_digit_chop(-0.12345))  # Correct Output: -0.12300
```